# Java regex filter headers

Tags: regex, text

I'm trying to filter headings from a big document.

Like this:

> 5.1.8 Reports
>
> 5 technische en applicatiearchitectuur
>
> this version number 5.5.5 (or 5.5) should stay in the text but the 2 sentences above should be removed

The problem is that I don't want to remove any version numbers etc. I tried `(\d.)`, but is there a way to write a regex that only removes headers and leaves the version numbers in the text?

Comment: Perhaps, you want `(?m)^(\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.).*` to replace with `$1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Im new to regex, could you please explain how the regex works ?

Comment: Does it work as expected? See https://regex101.com/r/uQRYRI/1. BTW, how did you try `(\d.)`? Note that `\d` matches a single digit and `.` matches any char but a line break char.

Comment: maybe my post wasnt specific enough i edited it.

Comment: The last `\.` should be made optional with a `?` after it. [`(?m)^(\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?).*`](https://regex101.com/r/uQRYRI/3). Or - if the spaces after are also to be removed, add `\h+`.

Comment: Thanks thats what im looking for! @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?m)^(\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?)\h+.*
```

Replace with `$1` backreference. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uQRYRI/3).

In Java:

```
String result = s.replaceAll("(?m)^(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*\\.?)\\h+.*", "$1");
```

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of the line
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?)` - Group 1:

  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)*` - 0+ sequences of a `.` followed with 1+ digits
  - `\.?` - an optional dot
- `\h+` - 1 or more horizontal whitespace
- `.*` - the rest of the line

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/bmB9wx):

```
String s = "5.1.8 Reports\n\n5 technische en applicatiearchitectuur\n\nthis version number 5.5.5 (or 5.5) should stay in the text but the 2 sentences above should be removed";
String result= s.replaceAll("(?m)^(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*\\.?)\\h+.*", "$1");
System.out.println(result);
```

Result

```
5.1.8

5

this version number 5.5.5 (or 5.5) should stay in the text but the 2 sentences above should be removed
```